# How to build pre-render pages based on environments

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

My requirement is to pre-render pages from CMS and store in S3.  In my app i have .env.development, .env.prod variables which holds the API endpoints of CMS.

I have two separate Jenkins job, one is for dev and another is for prod build. So when I start Jenkins job to build as "npm run build:dev" or "npm run build:prod" then it fetches JSON from CMS api endpoints defined in .env.development or .env.prod and creates build with version as "myapp-dev-<x.o>" or "myapp-prod-<x.o>" and upload in to nexus and also to S3.

But now the ask is to have a single build for both dev and prod and create only one version "myapp-<x.o>"
My question is how is it possible to have pre-rendered pages based on environments within the same build version?

Answer (score 1):

It is not perfect but you can do it.

**Have a customized `distDir`**

We will pass the different environmental variables to control the build directories.

```js
let distDir = 'devBuild';
if (process.env.BUILD_ENV === 'prod') {
  distDir = 'prod_build';
}
if (process.env.BUILD_ENV === 'stage') {
  distDir = 'stage_build';
}
```

**Run 2 different builds**

We need to run 2 builds with different variables to produce prod & stage builds. You can use `npm-run-all` to make npm scripts a bit easier to read.

```json
  "build": "npm-run-all --parallel build:production build:staging",
  "build:production": "BUILD_ENV=prod next build", 
  "build:staging": "BUILD_ENV=stage next build",
```

**Publish 2 builds in a single package**

Now you should have 2 different builds in `prod_build` and `stage_build`. You can deploy them at the same time, with a single package version.

you can sync to the corresponding S3 buckets from `prod_build` and `stage_build`.